# How to get paginated result in Spring JPA repository using Oracle 10g

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination

**AI_DpEntriesRepository.java**

```
public interface AI_DpEntriesRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AI_DpEntries, Long>{

    @Query(value = "select a.*,m.description,m.name from AI_DPENTRIES a,"
            + "MEDICALHIERARCHY m where PAGEID in (select pageid from PAGES where caseid=8960)"
            + " and a.HID=m.ID",nativeQuery = true)
    Page<AI_DpEntries> getLabAIDpEntries(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**AIDpEntryServiceImpl.java**

```
public class AIDpEntryServiceImpl implements AIDpEntryService{
    
    @Autowired
    private AI_DpEntriesRepository aiDpEntryRepository;

    @Override
    @Cacheable("labdpentries")
    public Page<AI_DpEntries> getAIDpEntries(int page,int size) {
     Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, 5);
     Page<AI_DpEntries> pageResult = aiDpEntryRepository.getLabAIDpEntries(pageRequest);
     List<AI_DpEntries> dpEntries = pageResult.getContent().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
     return new PageImpl<>(dpEntries, pageRequest, pageResult.getTotalElements());
     //return aiDpEntryRepository.getLabAIDpEntries();
    }

}
```

Getting **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "A": invalid identifier**
From repository call itself. What am i doing wrong? If i pass size parameter value as Integer.MAX_VALUE it returns all records at single time currently. But my requirement is to get 5 records per page

Comment: Please, post the full stack trace (formatted as code) and the SQL statement from logs which your JPA implementation actually tries to execute.

Comment: Solved it: Count query was required here along with query in repository and it should return same counts as rows returned by query method.

Comment: Please post a full answer, so others can benefit from it. Alternatively please delete the question.

Comment: @JensSchauder posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Solution here - There was a need for count query along with native query which would be returning same no. of rows to as returned by native query(PS-Minor change in query from question asked)

```
@Repository
public interface AI_DpEntriesRepository extends JpaRepository<AI_DpEntries, Long>{

@Query(value = "select a.*,m.description,m.name from AI_DPENTRIES a,
MEDICALHIERARCHY m where PAGEID in (select pageid from PAGES where caseid=8960) and a.HID=m.ID And (a.REVIEW_IND != 'D' OR a.REVIEW_IND IS NULL),
countQuery = "select * from AI_DPENTRIES where PAGEID in (select pageid from PAGES where caseid=8960) and (REVIEW_IND != 'D' OR REVIEW_IND IS NULL)",nativeQuery = true)

public Page<AI_DpEntries> getLabAIDpEntries(Pageable pageable);

}
```